# Getting last few rows from more than one tables in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, limit

i am pretty much stucked in an Sql Query from past few hours .  i need to get latest few elements from four tables as follows..
 table names are --  events , contactinfo , video , news

i need last 3 results from events and news and last single result from video and contactinfo..

i tried following query but as expected it didnt worked ..

```
SELECT  * FROM 
((SELECT * FROM EVENTS ORDER BY eventid DESC LIMIT 3)EV) INNER JOIN
((SELECT * FROM NEWS ORDER BY newsid DESC LIMIT 3)NE) INNER JOIN
((SELECT * FROM VIDEOS ORDER BY videoid DESC LIMIT 1)VI) INNER JOIN
((SELECT * FROM CONTACTINFO ORDER BY cid DESC LIMIT 1)AB);
```

Actually i am not a DB Expert i am a Developer and i really dont know much about MySql.
Any Help Would be Appreciated.

Comment: A full outer join might get you your answer.

Comment: INNER JOIN returns only rows that have equal key specified in ON clause of the expression.

Comment: @ Dan Bracuk Did you mean to say i should replace inner join with FULL OUTER JOIN ..

Comment: Replacing inner join with full outer join gets you started.  You'll have to do something about those select *'s though to make your result set more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If these tables have the same columns you can do a UNION (instead of your INNER JOIN). If not, I suggest doing 4 queries.

JOINs suggests that the data that is joined correlates to each other and if that's not the case than doing an JOIN seams like the wrong solution.

Comment: I thought union query as well, but it won't provide the required answer.  The order by and limit clauses will apply to the entire recordset and he needs specific events from each table.

Comment: @DanBracuk You can have subqueries with LIMIT unioned together.

Comment: I cant afford to use four queries @Andreas Wederbrand because i am using JDBC and chances of surviving with four queries without any comm. link failure exception is too less. so i HAVE to use only one query

Comment: @DanBracuk he can add an extra-field in every query with 1, 2, 3, 4 values depending on data source type and include it to the final ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

If you need result as a single table then use SELECT and UNION to union data, providing same column numbers and their data types in each query (CAST column and provide default values if need). Otherwise, if you need results with different structures then run 4 queries.
JOINs don't make sense for your task as last N rows from one table unlikely have corresponding rows within last N rows of another table.
**UPDATE**
See example:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 5 n.ID, n.Content, n.CreatedOn as CreatedOn, n.UserID as NewsUserID, 1 as SourceType FROM News n ORDER BY n.CreatedOn DESC) t1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 5 e.ID, e.Description as Content, e.CreatedAt as CreatedOn, NULL as NewsUserID, 2 as SourceType FROM Events e ORDER BY e.CreatedAt DESC) t2
ORDER BY SourceType, CreatedOn DESC
```

So i decided i want to have ID, Content and CreatedOn from every source, and also want to have UserID from News table. I built 2 queries so they return same columns of same datatypes. Each query takes only first 5 rows from source (TOP 5 is MS SQL syntax, please use your database's). Also i added an extra field SourceType that keeps type of entity. In the main query i union all results and order by source type first, then by CreatedDate.

Comment: So do you want single table or multiple as result?

Comment: i want it as one table as i cant efford to run four  queries .. is it even possible :(

Comment: @user2273752 Well, firstly decide what exactly you want in the result table. How do you think it looks like? Depending on this, you can solve problem by different ways.

Comment: Hey @jim i tried this  

    SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 1 n.newsID AS id, n.newstitle AS FIRST , n.newsdesc AS SECOND,
    n.newsdate AS third, n.ndate AS fourth,n.visible AS fifth,NULL AS sixth
    FROM News n ORDER BY newsid DESC) t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 5 e.eventID AS id, e.eventname AS FIRST, e.eventdesc AS SECOND,
     e.eventtime AS third, e.eventdate AS fourth,e.edate AS fifth,e.visible AS sixth
     FROM  EVENTS e ORDER BY eventid DESC) t2
     ORDER BY id DESC

Comment: But This Error Came

    Error Code: 1064
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
    your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 n.newsID as id,  
    n.newstitle as first , n.newsdesc as second, n.newsdate as thi' at line 2

Comment: @user2273752 i told you, "TOP N" syntax is for MS SQL, not MySQL. Use "LIMIT" instead (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: @user2273752 as you write "ORDER BY id DESC" in the end of the query, then you'll get all rows ordered by different IDs so your result will be like news row, event row, news row, video row etc. You need to add a column that differentiate sources (event, news, video) and include it into finel ORDER BY as first column.

Comment: yes @jim it worked after some modifications for me ..thanks a lot for support ... although this solution is not perfect but still something is good than nothing...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a logical way to get four table data in one call, since all tables are independent.

I think you wants to minimise database call,

In order to minimise database hits, you should use memcache instead of using such query.

Memcache :
It save data as key value pair, for each key you will get result set.
Its very fast.